# DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission() prompt text

Tags: ios, cordova, orientation

My Cordova app uses the DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission() function to request the user's permission to access the iOS device's orientation. But the prompt that iOS generates is:

> "" Would Like to Access Motion and Orientation

Any idea why the name is an empty string ("")? I assume this is supposed to be the app's name, but why is it empty?

Answer (score 0):

Webkit is trying to attach the hostname here and not finding it. I believe this is due to you using a redirect. Try accessing the page directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your hostname in config.xml

```
<preference name="scheme" value="MyApp" />
<preference name="hostname" value="MyApp" />
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to make sure the in your Info.plist file, the following fields are not empty:

- `CFBundleDisplayName`
- `CFBundleName`

Comment: Once again, StackOverflow has automatically marked an answer as accepted, when it is definitely not correct

Comment: @Flyingkiwi Do you have the correct answer?

Comment: Unfortunately not - I released with the empty string in the display message. I can confirm that I definitely already had the CFBundleDisplayName and CFBundleName set correctly.

One thing to try might be to use the http:// protocol instead of file:// and make sure the name is correct.  

I would be grateful if anyone who finds a solution would post it here.